# "Why" the speed of light is constant in all inertial frames?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

Light doesn't need s medium to travel neither a ball needs. So why the motion of ball is relative but light's motion is so special. If space and time adjust themselves to make the speed constant, they adjust by same "proportion" in every speed. So I ask again, "WHY" the speed of light is constant and why do it so different from motion of a ball? Provided that neither two needs medium to travel except the space itself!?

Comment: "the difficulty with answering a 'why' question is that you have to explain the answer in terms of something more fundamental. In this situation, there really isn't anything more fundamental; so the only answer I can give is that 'it just is that way in nature'" - a botched feynman quote

Answer (score 4):

If this were not so, then it would be possible to find a state of relative motion in which we would perceive effects before their causes, as follows.

Imagine a fire truck in the distance, speeding towards you on a straight, empty road. Between you and the truck is a side street on which a car is approaching the road with the truck on it. The car's path has it crossing the road a moment before the truck arrives there, and the truck swerves to miss the car in the intersection.

Since in this world the speed of light is additive, the light traveling from the truck is coming towards you faster than the light coming from the car, which is not traveling towards you. You therefore see the truck swerve to miss the car *before* the car enters the intersection.

But in *our* world, we never see effects before their causes like this, which argues against the additivity of the speed of light.

Comment: It does have a robust argument why light speed can't be additive in nature but it doesn't satisfy however, why it behaves as it does? I mean, I have not much knowledge of Q.M but I am sure that principles of Q.M can modify the principle of causality!

Comment: @SwayamJha, I'll try to help you with another example. the speed of light can be calculated from two constants of nature, the electric constant and the magnetic constant (look them up on wiki), both of which can be accurately measured in a lab. There's no reason those measurements should depend in any way on the speed of the lab, and indeed they do not, which means that neither should the speed of light. Let me know if this is helpful and we can continue the discussion if you like.

Comment: *"Since in this world the speed of light is additive, the light traveling from the truck is coming towards you faster than the light coming from the car"* This doesn't make sense. You're in the same frame of reference either way, so why would light from the truck be traveling faster? For an analogy, if compared in the same frame, sound from a moving object doesn't move faster than sound coming from a stationary object. You need an example where two observers move at different velocities relative to the source, yet they see the same speed of light relative to them.

Comment: @neilsneileon yeah, the electromagnetic property of light can explain its constant nature... But I don't know why -a kind of gut feeling- it's seems that we are missing something very deep and fundamental.

Comment: @BioPhysicist, light coming from the truck is coming at you faster because the truck's velocity adds to that of the light in this "unphysical" example.

Answer (score 1):

A century and a half ago, Maxwell figured out the equations governing electric and magnetic fields in free space and realized that light could be understood as waves supported by those equations: waves with a specific, very high speed (unlike the ball in your question which can vary in speed).

Every kind of wave that had ever been heard of needed a medium, and so it was assumed that light needed one too--the "ether", relative to which the light would propagate, and which would define a unique local rest frame.  The alternative was unthinkable, so it took Einstein to think it.

But you have accepted this: you start your question "Light doesn't need a medium to travel." The straightforward result of this is that the propagation speed of electromagnetic waves cannot depend on which inertial frame you're in: how would the waves even know?